# Windows 10 unable to add Visual FoxPro ODBC driver

Tags: windows-10, odbc, visual-foxpro

I am attempting to add the Visual FoxPro ODBC driver to my list of active data sources, but am unable to do so.

I have installed the latest driver downloaded directly from microsoft, and I have found the driver .dll file in windows explorer. However, when I attempt to add the data connection via ODBC Data Sources (32-bit), the driver does not come up in the available list.

I checked the list in ODBC Data Sources (64-bit), just to make sure it was not listed there. I am aware that the FoxPro ODBC driver is 32-bit only.
[image]

What next steps should I take in troubleshooting this issue? I've been googling for over two hours now, with no new developments. Thanks.

Comment: I hear what you're saying @Ramhound. The reason the issue cropped up was due to me upgrading microsoft excel from 2007 to 2010. While using excel 2007 on the same 64-bit OS, I was able to import Visual FoxPro data in Excel. Since upgrading, I found the option to not be availabe, and Im trying to basically, "get back to where I was"

Comment: Verify you didn't by accident install a 64-bit version of Excel.  I can already tell you that is **exactly** what you did because your Access driver is 64-bit.  *A 32-bit version of Excel cannot load a 64-bit driver.*  `FoxPro ODBC` drivers have been a problems for developers since Vista 64-bit was release.  You will have to uninstall the 64-bit version of Office and install the 32-bit version of Office as they both CANNOT be installed on the same system

Comment: @Ramhound Thanks for your help. I was hoping to be able to use the 64-bit version of excel, as my excel sheet has thousands of calculations, and was producing memory shortage errors while calculating. I can see now that this is not an option due to there not being a foxpro 64 bit driver. Thanks

Comment: I can't believe there isn't a third-party FoxPro OOBC driver.  As I said the problem has been around for over a decade now.  While you should seek to replace FoxPro with something that isn't ancient there are still legitimate business cases to use it.  If a business has a good enough reason to use it, that likely means somebody, came up with a solution.

Comment: @Ramhound There are third-party ODBC drivers, for example by Devart.

Comment: @AlanB - I am aware of that fact.  My comment is over 2 years old at this point.

Answer (score -1):

I was having a similar issue and found the MSI installer for the ODBC driver here:

http://www.topol.eu/articles/download%20odbc

Installed it on Windows 10 and is working properly.

Comment: Link does not work, besides that, I have a hard to believe the link actually has a 64-bit Visual FoxPro ODBC driver

Comment: There is no 64 bit Visual FoxPro ODBC Driver, as stated in the original question.  This is the 32 bit driver installer.  If the link I posted doesn't work for you, you can try Googling "VFPODBC.msi", which is how I located it.

Comment: The author would be unable to use a 32-bit ODBC driver with a 64-bit of Access/Excel.  Finding, the .msi was never the author's problem, you can download it directly from Microsoft.

Comment: It works fine on my 64-bit operating system.

Comment: It works because your not using a 64-bit installaton of Office.